# unable to listen the single digit port number? node js

Tags: node.js, server, port

In the servers port is of unsigned 16 bit so its range is 0>= to <=65535.
When i am trying to give 0 to 9 port number server starts but on browser it's unable to listen?

Are single digit port reserved for something?

Answer (score 4):

In many operating systems, ports below 1024 are restricted to privileged processes. On virtually all UNIX-like systems (Linux, BSD, ...) a process needs to run as `root` to be able to bind to ports 0 through 1023.

Ports in this range are also reserved in the sense that typically no new assignments are made (in IANA's official registry of what each port is used for).

More information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers#Well-known_ports